# Delphi XE5 can not trig Space bar

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

With Delphi XE5, The SpaceBar Can not be trig when using FormKeyUp or KeyDown Method.

The Key value is 0 (instead of 32) if you it the spacebar. This was working on XE2.

```
procedure TfrmMaster.KeyDown(var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = vkSpace then
  begin
    //custom handling
    //if SomeTest then Exit; //don't do default handling
  end;
  inherited; //do default handling
end;
```

Type is Desktop HD 
Target is Windows 32/64 bits and Mac OS

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It makes the question much more clear. I've removed my close vote and posted an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem in a new FMX HD application. A quick test shows that `vkSpace` is never sent.

- Create a new Firemonkey HD Desktop application
- On the `Events` tab in the Object Inspector, double-click the `OnKeyDown` event, and add the following code:

```
    procedure TForm4.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
      Shift: TShiftState);
    begin
      {
      if KeyChar = #32 then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Got space bar');
        KeyChar := #0;
      end;
      }
      if Key = vkSpace then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Got space bar');
        Key := 0;
      end
      else
        ShowMessage('Received key ' + IntToStr(Key));
    end;
```

- Run the application, and press <kbd>Space</kbd>.
- The second `ShowMessage` executes, and indicates it `Received key 0`.

There's a simple workaround. I tested using the following code:

```
    procedure TForm4.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
      Shift: TShiftState);
    begin
      if KeyChar = #32 then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Got space bar');  // Display message
        KeyChar := #0;                 // Discard keystroke
      end;
    end;
```

To allow the default processing of the keystroke after the `ShowMessage` call, simply remove the `KeyChar := #0;`.

Comment: Thanks, It's working on my set too by using KeyChar instead of Key parameter. On XE2 I was unsing Key parameters and it was working, when I have oppenned the project in XE5 the Key parameters seem to no longer working.